# Can the video chats on Messenger or WhatsApp be hacked?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, whatsapp-messenger, facebook-messenger, video-calling

I am using the Marshmallow version of android and often use the newly launched video call feature on WhatsApp and that of Messenger to talk to my family and friends. So usually a question arises, given there are lots of cyber crimes happening now-a-days, can my video chats be hacked ? If so how can I protect my phone from that? What are the tricks or ways hacker use to hacked the camera on my phone? If anyone can explain these things to me then it would be really helpful. I hope this question is allowed in this site. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In theory there is no way hack any video call because whatsapp include a point to point encryption.